# Can't get custom error rendering to work in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, oop, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm tring to customize error rendering in my form according to [this example](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers#chapter_03_sub_fine_grained_customization_of_error_messages).

Here is my code:

```
if ($this['message']->hasError()) {
  $error_msg = '<ul>';
  foreach ($this['message']->getError() as $error) $error_msg .= "<li>$error</li>";
  $error_msg .= '</ul>';
}

return $error_msg;
```

but when `$this['message']` has error this code returns `'<ul></ul>'` so it seems `foreach ($this['message']->getError() as $error)` causes no iterations

`$this['message']->getError()` returns `sfValidatorError` object - maybe something changed in symfony 1.4 and it isn't iterable anymore...

At first I thought that all magic in that example happened because of object being placed in `$error` by iteration implements __toString() but it seems no iterations happens at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have variable $form which holds the Form that you're displaying, and the code should be $form['message']->hasError() and $form['message']->getError() , where 'message' is a widget in your form. Do not use $this, as it doesn't hold the form in this context.

Comment: I use this code inside one of my form's method, so `$this` correctly references to my form. After all `$form['message']->hasError()` returns `true` so it is in a proper context.

Comment: can you paste exactly your action and view connected with this form ? and the form itself ? I want to see if you have maybe errors in the flow concept